# What is the lifespan of a Route Value redirected to another MVC action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio, variables

I have an ActionResult function that has one line in it which redirects to another action on the same controller:

```
Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.ct = Request.Url.Segments(1)})
```

Here's the question/problem: I am expecting the lifespan of that value arriving in the *Index* action to last until the page is rendered, and the next request from the user that value will be non-existent. Evidently, I am wrong about *something* because that value of *Request("ct")* is continuing to persist through dozens of clicks and pages on my development server (localhost:port). Something tells me that I'm about to feel stupid here, but "what" am I missing? Shouldn't the value disappear at the next request as long as it's not in the Url querystring? Also, since they are read-only, how would/could I change the value anyway?

*(VB.NET VS2015 MVC5 on localhost dev IIS Express)*

**EDIT -- Workaround (for me)**

1. Here's the ActionResult that receives the value from the URL and redirects the action to the "Index" Action:

   ```
   TempData("ct") = Request.Url.Segments(1)
   Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.ct = " "})
   ```

Assigning a single space (because if you assign "null" or "Nothing" it doesn't change anything) allows me to ".Trim.HasValue" and test the value in the next controller (".HasValue" is an extension that I created which returns a Boolean if the value is "empty" [there are plenty of other ways to do this]).

```
Request("ct").Trim.HasValue
```

TempData("ct"), of course, dies with the end of the current request. (Yay!)

Kind of "hacky" and not overly elegant but functional. I'm all ears if there's a better, more elegant way out there.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346. Many people find this behavior of MVC unnatural.

Comment: Wow. "Unnatural" (for me at least) would be an understatement. "It's not a bug -- it's a 'feature'!" Uh huh. I really appreciate the quick reply. I will go back to researching some more, but quick attempts (knowing what you have directed me to) to null-out the value proved fruitless, which BTW the value comes in as http://example.com/1234567890 -- where 1234567890 is the value that I am trying to get rid of. I guess this only happens on a RedirectToAction, right? My tests for values of *standard* query string additions expired at the next request. Is "my" problem that they are part of the URL?